# Trying to get Stack Overflow Access token Using "RestAssured"

Tags: support, oauth2, java

I have been trying to create an access token for a Stack Exchange app (already created). I am not even sure if I am using the correct URL `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token`.

```
RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive().basic(<My Client Id>,<My Client Key>)   
                      .formParam("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                      .formParam("scope", "")
                      .when()     .post("https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token");
```

I am getting the below error

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation
>   failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check
>   failed    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)     at

Comment: Welcome! It looks like step 4 of the [authentication flow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) is expecting other parameters than the ones you provide.